# Replace Android app that has the same package name but new keystore

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, package-name

We lost the keystore file for our Android application... And would like to replace the current application with a new app signed with a different keytore from the original app. If we unpublish the app, is it possible to upload the new app with same package name? Or are we forced to upload it with a new package name?

Edit: The `.keystore` file is missing, not the password.

Comment: As far as I know it has to be a different package name.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 So even if the old one is unpublished it wouldn't work?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I don't think being unpublished has to do anything. A new keystore means a new app and every app has unique package name.

Comment: Yes. It would n't work. But by using some steps you can retrieve your old keystore

Comment: @KingofMasses What steps? The `.keystore` file is missing, not the password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about Signing Application for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322777/question-about-signing-application-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you unpublish, re-sign your app with new certificate with new keystore and publish again, it will work.

Comment: If the same App is signed with a different key, any existing installations cannot be upgraded - the user will need to manually uninstall the old version and then install the new version.

Comment: @fab Normally? There is no guarantee that it will work?

Comment: @adelphus That is no problem, I just want be sure it will work before I get to work unpublishing and stuff.

Comment: You can try it with a stub application that you can publish temporarily on the store. It won't cost you a dime :P

Comment: @trevligheten if you unpublish the app, it is no more registered in google play store, this means you can use again same package name, you need to test :)

Comment: @trev you have to unpublish anyways, there is no way to upload an app to the old entry. Unpublishing just means its no longer available, but the users who have already installed it will still be able to use it.

Comment: I unpublished my app. Again signed with different keystore. But play store is not accepting from same account.

Comment: @Rahul Did you use the same package name? Did it work with a different package name?

Comment: @Schreiby Changing package name definitely works with new keystore! But cause loosing all existing app's history like: likes, comments, download counts and offcourse app itself.